# Unable to avoid mousewheel scrolling the whole page when capturing the mousewheel in youtube (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube

I'm trying to get a simple Chrome plugin to skip forward and backwards in youtube when the mousewheel is scrolled vertically.
That is working fine, but unfortunately the page also scrolls up and down when I use the mousehweel. I am trying to cancel the propagation of the mousewheel event with no success.

I have tried to no avail:

e.preventDefault();

return false;

e.stopImmediatePropagation();

Here is the code, as you can see I've tried many things.
There are only two JS files:

```
const playerdata = {
  "www.youtube.com" : {
    "keyCodes" : [39, 37],
    //"keyCodes" : [76, 74],
    "elem" : document
  }
}


var curPlayer = playerdata[location.host]

function triggerKeydown(forward) {
    //try {
          var elem;
          var e = new Event('keydown');
          
          e.keyCode = forward ? curPlayer.keyCodes[0] : curPlayer.keyCodes[1];
          if (typeof curPlayer.elem == "string") {
            elem = document.querySelector(curPlayer.elem)
          } else {
            elem = curPlayer.elem
          }
          //$(window).scrollTop(); // error on $
          
            
          e.preventDefault();
          elem.dispatchEvent(e);
          //e.preventDefault();
          //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //} catch(ex) {
        //alert(ex); // no error
    //}
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //return false;
    
}

document.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
  if (e.deltaX == 0 && e.deltaZ == 0) {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      //e.preventDefault();
      triggerKeydown(false);
    } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {
      //e.preventDefault();
      triggerKeydown(true);
      
    }
  }
});
```

```
function injectScript(file_path, tag) {
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', file_path);
    node.appendChild(script);
}

injectScript(chrome.extension.getURL('video-seek-mousewheel.js'), 'body');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `wheel` event is that it ain't synonymical to a `scroll` event. It merely means the user moved the mousewheel in a particular direction. So it is worthless to call a `preventDefault()` on the event as it won't be delegated to cause a movement of the browser's viewport..

What you want to achieve is just possible with a little trickery. If the user is hovering the element you want to be controllable using the mosuewheel, we 'disable' scrolling by resetting it's position using `window.scrollTo(x, y)`

Here's an example. Try hovering the slider and use your mouswheel:

```js
let theSlider = document.getElementById("rangeSlider");
let scrollTop, scrollLeft;
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", function(e) {
  if (document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY) == theSlider) {
    if (e.deltaX == 0 && e.deltaZ == 0) {
      scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      window.onscroll = dontScroll;
      if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        triggerKeydown(false);
      } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {

        triggerKeydown(true);
      }
    }
  } else {
    window.onscroll = scroll;
  }
});


function triggerKeydown(forward) {
  if (forward) {
    theSlider.value++;
  } else {
    theSlider.value--;
  }
  return false;
}

function scroll() {}

function dontScroll() {
  window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop);

}
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<input type="range" id="rangeSlider" min="0" max="10">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

### Workaround #2

As the above solution might fail if the user moves the mousewheel too fast here's another approach. This time if the user hovers the desired element, we simply set the overflow CSS property of the root  element to hidden. This will remove the scrollbars temporarely.

```js
let theSlider = document.getElementById("rangeSlider");
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", function(e) {
  if (document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY) == theSlider) {
    if (e.deltaX == 0 && e.deltaZ == 0) {
      if (e.deltaY > 0) {
        triggerKeydown(false);
      } else if (e.deltaY < 0) {
        triggerKeydown(true);
      }
    }
  }
});

theSlider.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].classList.add("noScroll");
});
theSlider.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].classList.remove("noScroll");
});

function triggerKeydown(forward) {
  if (forward) {
    theSlider.value++;
  } else {
    theSlider.value--;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.noScroll {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
<input type="range" id="rangeSlider" min="0" max="10">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried both workarounds, the 2nd one works best. But the window still scrolls down if the mousewheel is scrolled down more than once within a second. For "theSlider", I'm using the main video element: let theSlider = document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0];

Comment: Interestingly.. if I click another window and then hover the mouse over youtube, the page does not scroll (most of the time). If I move the mouse while scrolling, the scrollbar appears and the page starts scrolling again. So there seems to be a timing vs event glitch that I'm not sure how to fix.